# Why Spring Security is not filtering my queries?

Tags: spring-security

I'm trying to enable Spring Security for my REST API application, but my custom filter is not called.

This my configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SpringConfig {

    @Resource
    public AuthorizationFilter authorizationFilter;
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Enable CORS and disable CSRF
        http = http
                   .cors()
                       .and()
                   .csrf().disable();

        // Set session management to stateless
        http = http
                   .sessionManagement()
                       .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                       .and();

        // Set unauthorized requests exception handler
        http = http
                   .exceptionHandling()
                       .authenticationEntryPoint(
                          (request, response, ex) -> {
                            response.sendError(
                            HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
                            ex.getMessage()
                            );
                          }
                       )
                       .and();

        // Set permissions on endpoints
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                // Our private endpoints
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        // Add JWT token filter
        http
            .addFilterBefore(
                authorizationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class
            );
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

And this is my custom filter:

```java
@Component
public class AuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static final String AUTHORIZATION_HEADER = "Authorization";
    private static final String BEARER_PREFIX = "Bearer ";
    
    @Resource
    private ExternalAuthenticationService externalAuthenticationService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        final String header = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER);
        if (header != null && header.startsWith(BEARER_PREFIX)) {
            String token = header.replace(BEARER_PREFIX, "");
            if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(token)) {
                Identity id =externalAuthenticationService.verifyToken(token);
                if(id!=null)
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(id, null, Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(id.getType()))));
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

I expect all requests will pass the custom filter, but it doesn't work.
What I'm missing? Spring Security debug log is not helping.

Answer (score 0):

I missed a `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` class:

```java
@Order(2)
public class SecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

Adding this class, Spring Security is activated.